# How to display https image from HTML content in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

I current load html content (from JSON WS) inside TextView with this code :

```
if let stringHTML = contentHTML.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true) {

    do {
        let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(
            data: stringHTML,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        attrStr.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length), options: .init(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) in
            if let attachement = value as? NSTextAttachment {
                let image = attachement.image(forBounds: attachement.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location)!
                let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
                if image.size.width > screenSize.width-20 {
                    let newImage = image.resizeImage(scale: (screenSize.width-2)/image.size.width)
                    let newAttribut = NSTextAttachment()
                    newAttribut.image = newImage
                    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, value: newAttribut, range: range)
                }
            }
        })

        contentTextView.attributedText = attrStr
    } catch _ {
        contentTextView.text = ""
    }
}
```

This work correctly with http image but not for https.
I have set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true in my info.plist :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But not display https images.
The https image can be display in browser but certificat is untrusted. How can I allow untrusted https certificat?
Any idea?

Comment: Is you image available via https?

Comment: Yes, images in the html content are format like : <img src=' HTTPS://myserver/api/filestorages/download/5a17f58cb79b390037502615'/> (HTTPS is uppercase because not visible in stackoverflow comments if not)

Comment: I mean, can you copy the link from html into a browser (cache cleared) and you see your image?. Is the certificated a trusted one?

Comment: the link from html into browser work fine, but certificat is not a trusted one. Can I allow untrusted certificat to display image?

Comment: I only know how to do this for a web view... But I think this is your problem. Normally the browser ask you if you want to trust the certificate and you allow that. The app it self need to do the same thing, but I will not happen automatically.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs thanks for answers, I will edit my post

Comment: I try to give you a workaround

Answer (score 0):

**In Short: You need to trust or have a valid certificate**

> As a workaround this following approach could help

Do not use this code for production. It will just trust any certificate if there is an auth challenge.

Before you use your html try to make a request and trust the certificate.

You need to import the SessionDelegate like

```
YourController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate
```

then implement the auth challenge

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print("auth challange")
    let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
    let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
}
```

then call your website

```
let url : NSString = "https://yourwebite.com"

let urlStr : NSString = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)! as NSString
let searchURL : URL = URL(string: urlStr as String)!

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: searchURL, cachePolicy: NSMutableURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 300)

let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSession.shared.configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

})

task.resume()
```

There should come an auth challenge and it will trust it automatically. Maybe it will then be trusted for further calls too and you will get your images from https.

But like a said, this is maybe just a workaround. You need a trusted certificate.

Comment: Not working, (Can't have trusted certificate now, maybe late) I have error : - TIC SSL Trust Error -
 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
 - HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9813])

Comment: will the print("auth challenge") come? Also NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is set to true yet?

Comment: "auth challenge" found in log. and NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is always set tot true.

Comment: This is definitely the problem then why you don't get your images in your html. There is an auth challenge coming. You need to trust or have a valid certificate to get this working. So this will be the solution to your question.